# Deploying a Xamarin application from Windows to a local phone says succeeded but I can't see the app on the phone?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's the message I get when I try to deploy from Windows to my connected device:

```
Build succeeded.
2>Deployment was successful to Samsung SM-A705MN.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

However I cannot find the app on the phone.  Does anyone have any suggestions? Note that there are no error messages in the output log.

Comment: where have you looked?

Comment: Open Build menu -> Configuration Manager an ensure that Deploy checkbox it's marked

Comment: The deploy checkmark is clicked.  Everything runs normally but on the phone I don't see any app appearing.

Comment: Could you find it in your device `Settings` - `App & Notifications` ?